# Javascript run function from an object on an element

Tags: javascript

I'm building a form wizard and I want to achieve something similar like in jQuery

```
$('#table').DataTables();
```

This initializes some table with the DataTables plugin.

I already wrote some code for my form wizard

```
const form = document.getElementById('formSubscribe');

var formWizard = {
    steps: [
        {
            id: 'step1',
            name: 'personal',
            order: 1,
            required: true,
            disabled: false,
        },
        {
            id: 'step2',
            name: 'payment',
            order: 2,
            required: true,
            disabled: false,
        },
        {
            id: 'step3',
            name: 'confirmation',
            order: 3,
            required: true,
            disabled: false,
        },
    ],
    init: function (form) {
        element = document.getElementById(form);
    },
    disableStep: function (stepName) {
        let stepToDisable = this.steps.find((step) => step.name == stepName);
        stepToDisable.disabled = true;
        this.updateFormWizard();
    },
    update: function () {},
};

formWizard.init('formSubscribe');
```

How could i achieve the same in javascript so i could do something like this? The intention is to initialize the plugin to an element like it happens in jQuery, element + plugin name, store it in a variable after and then i can run methods from that variable

```
var formWizard = form.FormWizard();
formWizard.init(form);
formWizard.update();
```

I forgot to say that i don't use jQuery here.

**EDIT**

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it but I have achieved something similar

```
// GLOBAL VARIABLES
const form = document.getElementById('formSubscribe'); // get the form
const formWizard = FormWizard(form); // initialize form wizard on the form

console.log(formWizard);

// FUNCTIONS

/*******************************
    Form Wizard Builder. 
    - PARAMS: form 
    - RETURNS: form wizard object initialized to the form
*******************************/
function FormWizard(form) {
    if (form === null || form === undefined) {
        throw new TypeError('Element must not be null!');
    }

    let formWizard = {
        form: form,
        steps: [
            {
                id: 'step1',
                name: 'personal',
                order: 1,
                required: true,
                disabled: false,
            },
            {
                id: 'step2',
                name: 'payment',
                order: 2,
                required: true,
                disabled: false,
            },
            {
                id: 'step3',
                name: 'confirmation',
                order: 3,
                required: true,
                disabled: false,
            },
        ],
        init: function (form) {
            this.form = form;
        },
        disableStep: function (stepName) {
            let stepToDisable = this.steps.find(
                (step) => step.name == stepName
            );
            stepToDisable.disabled = true;
            this.updateFormWizard();
        },
        update: function () {},
    };

    formWizard.init(form);
    return formWizard;
}
```

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/
This link should help you. You can write $.fn.FormWizard().

Comment: Sorry forgot to say i don't use jquery

Comment: What is the problem you are running into? I'm not seeing a question anywhere, more of a statement of what you've done so far. Also, don't you also have to supply `formWizard.init()` with the form ID?

Comment: @DillanWilding edited, forgot to add a question mark

Comment: I think you can try it and try to understand the source code.  This is a big project. https://github.com/Mobius1/Vanilla-DataTables

Comment: @LianSheng yep this is a good start, thanks